# Data Driven Pages Optimization for the same FC referenced twice

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, performance, data-driven-pages, definition-query

I have a feature class that I am referencing twice in my map,

1. for "active" features that are "the subject" of the map page as a Feature Layer
2. second Feature Layer that is grayed out/"inactive" on the map.

Is it faster/more efficient for ArcMap to reference the same Feature Class twice or if I would see some improvement if I made a copy of the data in the same geodatabase since I'm making about 15,000 pages?

These two layers are being "filtered" based on the "Match" / "Doesn't Match" criteria in the page definitions queries.

Answer (score 1):

This sounded like a familiar question:

[GeoNet question on DQ efficiency](https://community.esri.com/message/588336)

Usually, whether something is "active" could change frequently, which would tilt the answer toward using definition queries.

Another point to consider, perhaps a long shot, is do you have secondary indexes (non-key-field attribute indexes) on any fields? Can you add one on the active status field and try rerunning the query? A secondary index can speed sorting and joining; I am not sure if ArcMap utilizes this well when doing selects.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use case for [Page Definition Queries](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/using-page-definition-queries.htm):

> Page Definition Queries allow you to specify which features of a layer
>   draw based on an SQL query. Though similar to other definition
>   queries, Page Definition Queries differ in that they only work with
>   Data Driven Pages and are dynamic. Features are filtered based on the
>   current page. As you iterate through the pages, the query changes, and
>   a new set of features draw appropriate to the new page.

You would use **Matc**h for "active" features, and **Don't Match** for "inactive" features.

Comment: So I am using that, but I am symbolizing based on whether it matches or doesn't. The question is about whether or not performance is affected if I have two layers of the same feature class, or if it would be faster if I referenced a different, but identical feature class.

Comment: @bwp8nt the way to determine that is by running and timing the two alternatives.

Comment: Agreed, the intent was to understand if there was an underlying and known conflict in the software. I'll have to design an experiment i guess...